# Opening an Infopath Document in a browser

Tags: infopath, browser-compatibility

I have my InfoPath document set to open in the browser, but when I try to open it from SharePoint I get an error that says:

> Error: This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form,
>   use Microsoft InfoPath

.  Does anyone know how to fix this so that my InfoPath document opens in the browser?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Foundation or Server?

Answer (score 1):

In InfoPath, there's a setting to only use components that are browser compatible. There's also a way to check before publishing whether the form is browser-compatible. It's likely you've included something that isn't.

[List of Compatible Parts](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Web-browser-compatibility-in-InfoPath-Forms-Services-0356450c-82ec-40a5-b145-c7e935f73fdc)

[Setting to only allow compatible parts](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Specify-the-compatibility-settings-for-a-form-template-dfbcca29-ddb3-4aeb-8a57-d9dbb2e1a660)

[Design checker - Check compatibility](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Introduction-to-browser-compatible-form-templates-7A6E40FF-EB1D-4311-945D-169857D340AF#bm5)